# Regex Split Around Curly Braces

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have a string like :

```
"abc{d}efg{hi}{jk}lm{n}"
```

And I want it to be split into:

```
"abc","{d}","efg","{hi}","{jk}","lm","{n}"
```

I used this pattern `[{}]` and the result is `"abc","d","efg","hi","","jk","lm","n"`

How do I keep the `'{'`and`'}'` there? And how do I remove the empty `""` between `'}'`and`'{'`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Use Match All instead of Split

Remember that [Match All and Split are Two Sides of the Same Coin](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#splitvsmatch).

Use this regex:

```
{[^}]*}|[^{}]+
```

See the matches in the **[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dU5lQ3/14)**.

To see the matches:

```
var myRegex = new Regex("{[^}]*}|[^{}]+");
Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(yourString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

**Explanation**

- On the left side of the alternation `|`, the `{[^}]*}` matches `{content in braces}`
- On the right side, `[^{}]+` matches any chars that are not curlies

Comment: That is awsome man! Why didn't I ever think about using Match instead of Split? Cheers!

Comment: Yeah it's something really good to keep in mind: when you want to split, consider Match All, and when you want to match all, consider splitting. FYI added explanation and sample code. :)

Answer (score 2):

not tested but hopefully this will work in your split:

```
(?={)|(?<=})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of lookaround assertions:

```
String s = @"abc{d}efg{hi}{jk}lm{n}";
String[] parts = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=^|})|(?={)");
foreach (string value in parts)
         Console.WriteLine(value);
```

Output

```
abc
{d}
efg
{hi}
{jk}
lm
{n}
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work! Any solution(using Regex pattern) about the empty spaces between '}'and'{'?

Comment: Nice hwnd but needs something to prevent the empty first string currently returned by the split, how about `(?<=})|(?!^)(?={)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Parse the string until you get to an opening brace. Output the substring until that position. Parse the substrings after the opening brace until a closing brace is found. Output the substrings between the braces with the braces. Continue this algorithm until end of string.

Comment: I did this before. But I want Regex pattern here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way to do it

```
string to_split = "abc{d}efg{hi}{jk}lm{n}";
            var splited = Regex.Matches(to_split, @"\{[\w]*\}|[\w]*");
            foreach (Match match in splited)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but splitting removes the split delimiter so at the moment this will remove the whole string. :)