# JavaScript Split around curly braces

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string format inside of a string variable:

```
"{0} Hello World {1}"
```

I need to split it into something like this:

```
"{0}","Hello World","{1}"
```

From what I have tried the best I could get was:

```
"","0"," Hello World ","1",""
```

I have tried converting the examples from [Regex Split Around Curly Braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051058/regex-split-around-curly-braces)
but it did not work, the split there either deleted everything or kept the spaces and removed the `{}`.

So, my questions is the same as in the other article, how do I keep the braces `{}` and remove spaces after and before them not in between the words?

Comment: `split /({\d+})/`. the () force javascript to return the thing-you-split-on as part of the split data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Split` with a regex having capturing group(s)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing
>   parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results
>   (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are
>   spliced into the output array.

```js
var re = /\s*(\{[0-9]+\})\s*/g;
var splt = "{0} Hello World {1}".split(re).filter(Boolean);
alert(splt);
```

Regex explanation:

- `\s*` - Any number of whitespaces
- `(\{[0-9]+\})` - A capturing group that matches:

  - `\{` - a literal `{`
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
  - `\}` - a literal `}`
- `\s*` - Any number of whitespaces

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can help get rid of empty elements in the array.

> `filter()` calls a provided callback function once for each element in
>   an array, and constructs a new array of all the values for which
>   callback returns a true value or a value that coerces to `true`.
>   callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned
>   values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which
>   have never been assigned values.
>  Array elements which do not pass the
>   callback test are simply skipped, and are not included in the new
>   array.

Comment: Wohooo :D Thank You very much! Wored perfectly :D

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following:

```
\s*({\d+})\s*
```

JS Code:

```js
var regex = /\s*({\d+})\s*/g;
var split_string = "{0} Hello World {1}".split(regex).filter(Boolean);
alert(split_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var myregexp = /({.*?})(.*?)({.*?})/im;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
   if (match != null) 
   {
     result1 = match[1];
     result2 = match[2];
     result3 = match[3];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter out the empty strings if you want:

```
var s = "{0} Hello World {1}";
s.split(/({\d+})/).filter(Boolean);
```

which returns

```
["{0}", " Hello World ", "{1}"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myString = "{0} Hello World {1}"
var splits = myString.split(/\s?{\d}\s?/);
```

which would return ["", "Hello World", ""],

```
var count = 0;
for (var i=0; i< splits.length; i++) {
    if (splits[i] === "") {
        splits[i] = "{" + count + "}";
        count++;
    }
}
```

now splits would have what you need.