# javaScript - splitting string in array that matches pattern

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have got for following string as an example

```
hello {{salutation}} {{ name }} we are glad to tell you {{ message }}
```

I would like to have an array like this:

```
["hello", "{{salutation}}", "{{ name }}", "we are glad to tell you", "{{ message }}"]
```

Is this possible in with native functions? or do i have to make a workaround?

Comment: You don't have to make a workaround. You have to write code. Writing code that is not readily available is not a workaround.

Comment: First why do you want to do that ?! To replace all `{{var}}` with another thing ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adapt the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30576287/1447675) of [Split around curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576177/javascript-split-around-curly-braces) with search for more curly brackets and inside with any characters except a closing curly bracket

```js
var string = 'hello {{salutation}} {{ name }} we are glad to tell you {{ message }}',
    array = string.split(/\s*(\{\{[^}]+}})\s*/).filter(Boolean);
    
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[{]+[^}]+[}]+|[\w\s]+/g`

```js
var str = "hello {{salutation}} {{ name }} we are glad to tell you {{ message }}";

var res = str.match(/[{]+[^}]+[}]+|[\w\s]+/g);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Nice one ! Good job.. But, I thing his problem isn't here, and he didn't go on the right direction. Trying to understand what's the real purpose of that

Comment: You can chain `.map(s => s.trim()).filter(Boolean)` to remove trailing empty string